# Which FHIR resource should I use for Treatment Preferences?

Tags: hl7-fhir

While trying to understand how an existing system will map to FHIR resources, I am stuck in the documentation on Treatment/Care Preferences like the ones outlined here: http://wiki.hl7.org/index.php?title=Care_Preference

Would these preferences be handled in a list of extended objects? Or will FHIR be implementing a CarePreference resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't catered for in the current set of resources. I guess you use Other (http://hl7.org/implement/standards/fhir/other.htm). It does seem like the kind of thing we'd want to define a resource for, but I'm not aware of any plans for one right now. I forwarded the suggestion along to the appropriate team.

btw, I'm not sure this question meets Stack Overflows guidelines - it might get edited/closed.

Comment: This question is probably in the grey area, you are right. But seeing that it is a question of data representation where there is already an HL7 defined resource and the other hl7-fhir questions are similar in nature, I believe that it useful. Where would be the best place to get this kind of information? The wiki is out of date in most places and very messy...

Comment: I don't mind you asking this question here, but the editors have a policy of killing questions they don't like :-(. Agree the wiki is messy - it's a wiki - but probably, as a design of FHIR question (maybe - agree it's in the grey area) - the place to ask is the FHIR mailing list at HL7

Answer (score 1):

"Other" is the solution for now.  Speed of the development of a specific resource is likely to be dependent on the number asking for it and the detail of the use-cases they supply.  Consider sharing these on the FHIR list server.  Alerts might be another mechanism to flag important preferences.